# Python3, Beautifulsoup isn't returning anything?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the product names of credit cards on Bank of America's website but even when I just try to navigate to the div I want, it doesn't return anything.

If I can navigate to this section, I think I can figure out the find_all and everything else to print out just what I need.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.bankofamerica.com/credit- 
cards/#filter').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

ProductCard = soup.find('div', className_='small-12 medium-9 columns')

print (ProductCard)
```

I expect my code to return everything within the

What I see is "None". I've confirmed that I've installed both BeautifulSoup and lxml.

Comment: I tried changing className_ to class_ and that, unfortunately, hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: These divs are loaded with javascript which is not supported by `requests` (if you `print(source)` you will not find any div with that class). You should use selenium or one of the headless browsers available for Python

Comment: Actually there are several errors: first the div name should be columns small-12 medium-9 and "className_" parameter should be replaced. The call should be : ProductCard = soup.find('div', 'columns small-12 medium-9')

Comment: And maybe you need to simulate a Post